# Issues updating users with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Devise to handle all session information and user authentication - but I wanted to add the ability for an admin to edit the user's profile information (Name, address, etc)

I've created a user_controller to allow admins to update the user information for other profiles.  All of the forms appear correctly, and when an admin edits the user information the "User was successfully updated" appears - but the information is not actually updated to the DB.

Here are the relevent methods in my users_controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy] # probably want to keep using this


  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
    unless current_user && current_user.admin?
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Must be signed in as Admin"
    end
  end


  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

And here is the form:

```
<%= form_for(user) do |f| %>
  <% if user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :first_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :last_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :address %>
    <%= f.text_field :address %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :city %>
    <%= f.text_field :city %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :state %>
    <%= f.text_field :state %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

I feel as though I must be missing something obvious, but I can't seem to wrap my head around this enough to find it.

Thanks in advance for any help - and please let me know if I've left something out that's needed to get a better picture!

EDIT:

Here is the output as the updated form is submitted:

```
Started PATCH "/users/5" for 73.104.86.133 at 2017-07-16 12:16:02 +0000
Cannot render console from 73.104.86.133! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 
127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by UsersController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", 
"authenticity_token"=>"**truncated**", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"Tests", 
"last_name"=>"Accounts", "address"=>"12345 Main St", "city"=>"Atlantis", 
"state"=>"FL"}, "commit"=>"Update User", "id"=>"5"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Unpermitted parameters: first_name, last_name, address, city, state
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to **truncated**/users/5
Completed 302 Found in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started GET "/users/5" for 73.104.86.133 at 2017-07-16 12:16:02 +0000
Cannot render console from 73.104.86.133! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 
127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"5"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering users/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (3.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 86ms (Views: 81.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

Comment: Can you post the log that appears as soon as you submit the form?

Comment: I have added the output to the original question.

Comment: Post the `user_params` method

Comment: The user_params were missing the correct attributes - this fixed the issue, thank you!